How to implement indented display trait for struct or enum in rust
I have this enum which can store points as well as list of points.
pub enum Point {
    List(Option<Vec<Point>>),
    Point2D(Option<Box<[i32; 2]>>),
    Point3D(Option<Box<[i32; 3]>>),
}

I want to implement display trait, also it should with indentation like this.
List[
    Point2D[1, 2]
    Point3D[3, 4, 5]
    List[
        Point2D[6, 7]
        Point3D[8, 9, 10]
        List[
            Point2D[11, 12]
            Point3D[13, 14, 15]
        ]
    ]
]

The rust playground link
use std::fmt::{self, Display};

pub enum Point {
    List(Option<Vec<Point>>),
    Point2D(Option<Box<[i32; 2]>>),
    Point3D(Option<Box<[i32; 3]>>),
}

impl Display for Point {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> core::fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Point::List(Some(points)) => {
                let mut res = String::new();
                res.push_str("List[\n");
                for point in points {
                    res.push_str(&point.to_string());
                    res.push_str("\n");
                }
                res.push_str("]");
                write!(f, "{}", res)
            }
            Point::Point2D(Some(point)) => write!(f, "Point2D[{}, {}]", point[0], point[1]),
            Point::Point3D(Some(point)) => {
                write!(f, "Point3D[{}, {}, {}]", point[0], point[1], point[2])
            }
            _ => write!(f, "None"),
        }
    }
}

/*
List[
    Point2D[1, 2]
    Point3D[3, 4, 5]
    List[
        Point2D[6, 7]
        Point3D[8, 9, 10]
        List[
            Point2D[11, 12]
            Point3D[13, 14, 15]
        ]
    ]
]
*/

fn main() {
    let point = Point::List(Some(vec![
        Point::Point2D(Some(Box::new([1, 2]))),
        Point::Point3D(Some(Box::new([3, 4, 5]))),
        Point::List(Some(vec![
            Point::Point2D(Some(Box::new([6, 7]))),
            Point::Point3D(Some(Box::new([8, 9, 10]))),
            Point::List(Some(vec![
                Point::Point2D(Some(Box::new([11, 12]))),
                Point::Point3D(Some(Box::new([13, 14, 15]))),
            ])),
        ])),
    ]));

    println!("{}", point);
}


Not an answer, but don't allocate a temporary String in your Display implementation. You should write directly in the formatter instead (e.g. use write!(f, "List[\n") instead of res.push_str ("List[\n").

Take a look at what the stdlib does for pretty-printing Debug formats; it uses a specialized DebugFormatter with a PadAdapter, as you can see in the source behind the relevant docs

Also that's hooked into Formatter::alternate() which allows toggling it on/off.

You can implement a private method to generate String from Self, with an additional indention parameter.
playground
use std::fmt::{self, Display};

pub enum Point {
    List(Option<Vec<Point>>),
    Point2D(Option<Box<[i32; 2]>>),
    Point3D(Option<Box<[i32; 3]>>),
}

const INDENT: &str = "    ";

impl Point{

    fn push_indent(indent: u32, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>)-> fmt::Result{
        for _ in 0..indent {
            write!(f, "{}", INDENT)?;
        }
        Ok(())
    }

    fn to_string(&self, indent: u32, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        Point::push_indent(indent, f)?;
        match self {
            Point::List(Some(points)) => {
                writeln!(f, "List[")?;
                for point in points {
                    point.to_string(indent + 1, f)?;
                    writeln!(f)?;
                }
                Point::push_indent(indent, f)?;
                write!(f, "]")
            }
            Point::Point2D(Some(point)) => write!(f, "Point2D[{}, {}]", point[0], point[1]),
            Point::Point3D(Some(point)) => write!(f, "Point3D[{}, {}, {}]", point[0], point[1], point[2]),
            _ => write!(f, "None"),
        }
    }
    
}

impl Display for Point {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        self.to_string(0, f)
    }
}

/*
List[
    Point2D[1, 2]
    Point3D[3, 4, 5]
    List[
        Point2D[6, 7]
        Point3D[8, 9, 10]
        List[
            Point2D[11, 12]
            Point3D[13, 14, 15]
        ]
    ]
]
*/

fn main() {
    let point = Point::List(Some(vec![
        Point::Point2D(Some(Box::new([1, 2]))),
        Point::Point3D(Some(Box::new([3, 4, 5]))),
        Point::List(Some(vec![
            Point::Point2D(Some(Box::new([6, 7]))),
            Point::Point3D(Some(Box::new([8, 9, 10]))),
            Point::List(Some(vec![
                Point::Point2D(Some(Box::new([11, 12]))),
                Point::Point3D(Some(Box::new([13, 14, 15]))),
            ])),
        ])),
    ]));

    println!("{}", point);
}


It will be more efficient to just append four spaces to the indentation, and more efficient to write directly to the formatter without intermediate string.

@ChayimFriedman the second advice has been updated. but the first advice I have no idea what you mean.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1adcac047b94c1cedf2d537b8557d05f.
